# How to copy a whole DB Scheme using java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am creating a middle ware for our MySQL db. Part of what I need is to allow users using my middle ware to copy a chosen scheme to a new scheme with a different name.
The scheme that I am copying should be copied with the store procedures and all the table data like indexes and etc.

Now I know how to do this using the cmd but how can I do this using java?
Another point is that the pc running the adapter doesn't have a MySQL server so I can't use the MySQL dump from the cmd through java.

Comment: But you can export the schema from the cmd? If so just do this and execute the exported statements with jdbc.

Comment: in genrale i know how to export and import the scheme in mysql. what i need now is a way to do this without using my sqldump. i need this becuse the location of the mysql dump can change nad i dont want to look for it plu the aplication my be executed on a computer that dosent have the mysqldump on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the queries:

> show tables;

returns you the list of tables in the db;

> show create table _table_name_

will return you the scheme of the table. (it includes keys, indexes)

> show procedure status

list of procedures

> show create procedure _procedure_name_

procedure code

Comment: so what you are suggesting is to read the return values as string and then parse it and re run the queries?

Comment: Something like this. I don't think you should parse something. Just to use the result.

Comment: ok i will try. but to be honest i find it very strange that the jdbc doesn't have methods to copy a schema or a code implantation of mysql dump. any how thank you @absurbum